# Problem with ssl in Visual Studio and ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ssl

I run the application via IIS Express. If you check this box, the browser returns the error

> This site can't be reached

The application was created from scratch and no code was changed.

If I use this command

```
C:\Program Files\IIS Express> .\IisExpressAdminCmd.exe setupsslUrl -url:https://localhost:44376 -UseSelfSigned
```

then everything will work for the specified url, but if you create another application, it does not work again.

How to make the application run at any url?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Right click the IIS Express icon, and check whether there have running application which using the same port, refer [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kd749.gif). If the port is used, try to use another port to run your application. Besides, when you debug the application, try to select the project name launches the Kestrel web server, refer [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0#development-and-launchsettingsjson). If the app works well on Kestrel, you could check the launchSettings file, the issue might relate it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are facing this bug: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/16892

Try repair in Visual Studio Installer.